# Persistent Navigation Bar in XAML for Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

How do I implement a persistent navigation bar. Basically an app bar that cannot be dismissed even by the right click action. MS as referred to this in this article ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn440584.aspx ) when discussing the flat navigation in the calculator app and also here ( http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/05/13/windows-store-refresh-makes-it-easier-to-find-apps/ ) when reviewing changes to the windows store app in windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NavigationPart" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Home" />
        <Button Content="Products" />
        <Button Content="Contact" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentPart" />
</Grid>
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question i started googling and was not able to find any already available app bars for that. So as far as i know there is nothing like persistent App Bar. IsSticky property does help to some extent but still can be dismissed by right click.

**But still you can customize things by yourself...**

As for eg. you have referred [this page](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/05/13/windows-store-refresh-makes-it-easier-to-find-apps/) in your question.

[image: The Persistent App Bar]

You can make your own implementation for the same.

**This is my implementation just to get you started...**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.BlankPage5"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Green">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/windows-image.jpg" />    
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>

                <TextBlock Text="Home" FontSize="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Top Charts" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Categories" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Collection" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Accounts" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Width="110" Height="110">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/back.png" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>

            <TextBlock  Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Text="Store" FontSize="70" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
            <TextBlock Text="Your Content Here" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="100" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**It produces the following output :**

[image: Program Output]

**I have not worked on the respective event handlers and i hope you can do that according to your needs.**

**A Basic Advice :** Don't try to make too many changes to the already available design templates. Stick to them and only apply the required changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Akshay Soam. I was actually looking to share the persistent navbar across all pages. I found that the CustomAppBar from the 'WinRT XAML Toolkit' has a CanDismiss property that can be forced to keep the appbar open.

Comment: and yes for sharing app bar across all pages you can make it as a xaml user control... that can make things easier for you...

Comment: Here's a link to the toolkit: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/ look for CustomAppBar  under the controls section